# php download multiple .zip files from xml

Tags: php, zip

i want to download some .zip files with php from a xml file...

Example of XML Code:

> `<Index>
>    <Package unzip="false" ignore="false">
>     <FileSize val="xxxxx" />
>      <FileName val="folder1:file1.zip" />
>      <Language val="all" />
>    </Package>
>    <Package unzip="false" ignore="false">
>     <FileSize val="xxxxx" />
>      <FileName val="folder2:file2.zip" />
>      <Language val="all" />
>    </Package>
>   </Index>`

As you can see in Filename there are different (unknown) specifications where the files are on my server... for example in folder1 there is file1.zip

And when i download them i also want them in the defined folders, so i want to have file1.zip in folder1

So here is my php Code, i've got all the filenames and folders (changed : to /) but i cannot download them

php Code:
`

> $sxe = simplexml_load_file(test.xml');
>
> foreach($sxe->xpath('//FileName/@val') as $item) {
>
> ```
>   $item = str_replace(":", "/", $item);
>
>   file_put_contents($item, fopen('http://aServer.com/'.$item, 'r'));
> ```
>
> }
>   `

Output error:
failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Will be thankful for every help

Comment: `fopen` is used to get local files, you will want to use `file_get_contents` instead

Comment: lol, getting this error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: use `set_time_limit(0);` to allow your script to not timeout

Comment: Now i've get no error message but also there are now no directorys or files wich i wanted to download, here's my code `file_get_contents('http://server.com/files/'.$item, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);` using XAMPP on Windows

Comment: SOLVED it... the Problem was not file_get_contents, it was that there is not such a folder in download path... Anyway, Thanks for help